# APK does not install and device is unauthorized and offline

Tags: android-studio, adb

I have a device running Android 6.0.1 and I'm working with Android Studio 2.3.3 on a Mac. When I try to install/run my application (hello world) I get this message.

```
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set 
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong. 
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
Error while Installing APK
```

I know questions like this have been asked all over this site and I have looked though most of them and followed these suggestions

1. Turn everything off and on a few times
2. Ensure USB debugging in enabled in developer settings
3. Stop and start the adb server
4. Try a different deployment target, virtual devices work fine

My current theory is that my device is not authorized either because my device is not a phone/tablet/watch, it is just a SOM and carrier board.

My only other thought is that this is caused by the device being offline. 
When I am selecting a deployment target I can see my device but it says [OFFLINE] beside it and it is slightly greyed out. I don't fully understand what this means given my device is connected the same network as my Mac they can ping each other.

So my question comes down to this

1. What other troubleshooting can I try?
2. Is it relevant that my device is offline/ what does that mean/ how can I go online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the .img file I used when getting the OS running on my device. I reinstalled the OS and everything worked after that.